# Error when logging into .Mil Salesforce Domain

Tags: workbench

When logging into workbench with my custom .mil domain I get the error "Host must be a Salesforce domain"

is there a way to add the .mil to the domains list or an alternative login solution that I should be using?

Comment: That's a limitation of current Workbench implementation: https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/main/workbench/controllers/LoginController.php#L232 . Since Workbench is in maintenance mode, you'll have to try another tool such as [Visual Studio Code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/set-up-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Do you think it is possible for me to fork the git repo, update the domains allowed, then run my own instance of workbench?

Comment: Yes, that's another way to go.